# discrepancy between union probability and sum of mutually exclusive events?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider the following probability game. Consider a ballot box in which there are 2 winning ballots and 4 unwinning ballots. If the player has two chances to draw a ball, what is the probability that the player wins only one prize?

Call A the event of winning on the first try and let B be the event of winning on the second try. Since the player can only win one prize, it is clear that these events are mutually exclusive.

\textbf{If there is a replacement of ballots}, we calculate the probability that the player wins only once, that is, given that the events are mutually exclusive, when calculating $P(A\cup B)$, we would be calculating the probability that $A$ occurs or $B$ occurs but not both, since in this case $P(A\cap B) = 0$, that is:
$$
P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B)
$$
In fact, it is clear that $P(A) = \frac{2}{6}$. Now to calculate the probability of winning on the second try, I'm not sure if we consider only $\frac{2}{6}$, since there is replacement and we would be back at the beginning or if we should consider that the player lost on the first try. I try and win on the second, that is: $P(B) = \frac{4}{6}\cdot\frac{2}{6} = \frac{2}{9}$, suppose I choose the second option, we now add these events and we get $P(A\cup B) = \frac{2}{6}+\frac{2}{9} = \frac{5}{9}$,.

The doubt is that if we consider another way of calculating the same, when considering the case where we win in the first and do not win in the second, that is: $\frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{4}{ 6} = \frac{2}{9}$, and analogously, the event where we do not win on the first try and win on the second, the probability is given by $\frac{4}{6}\cdot \frac {2}{6} = \frac{2}{9}$. In this way of calculating the probability it seems that we are also calculating the same previous probability, winning in the first or in the second but not in both, however, the results are not the same as the previous reasoning, since in this case it is $\frac{2}{9} + \frac{2}{9} = \frac{4}{9}$ Why don't you get the same result? Which one is correct?

Comment: Will you first specify clearly whether the draws are with replacement or without replacement ? When you say that the player can win only one prize, how is this done ? Is he not allowed a second draw if the first has yielded a prize, or what ?

Comment: You write "...what is the probability that the player wins only one prize?..." and also write "...Since the player can only win one prize,..." It is a very confused sort of question. Put up a *clear* question

Comment: "Since the player can only win one prize, it is clear that these events are mutually exclusive....".  Unclear what you are saying here.  I **speculate** that you are confused, and that the problem composer intends that it is possible for someone to win both prizes.  So, the two events of winning on the 1st ballot, and winning on the 2nd ballot are not mutually exclusive.